# SQL: insert a field that already exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a unique field (a URL). What would be the best practice when trying to insert a URL into the table:

- check if it exists via the code and 
  do not insert if it doesn't
- just go ahead and insert and don't mind 
  the error it creates if the url is 
  already there
- insert ignore

Answer (score 4):

Try this....

MySQL has a special construct for this. Assume that the 'FirstName' column below is UNIQUE:

```
INSERT INTO users (FirstName, RollNumber) VALUES ('Hiu', '12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RollNumber= '12'
```

The 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' statement only works on PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE columns.

Comment: +1 (nitpick: it's an *index* which is `UNIQUE`, and an index doesn't have to be on a single column; for example, in a "votes" table on SO (if it were MySQL), you might have a `UNIQUE` index on `user_id,answer_id` - so a user can vote on multiple answers, and an answer can be voted on by multiple users, but a single user can only cast a single vote on an answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`url`) VALUES ('http://example.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `url`='http://example.com'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the error when the insert fails. A select is useless, concurrent users can insert a new value one microsecond later and the result of your select is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need the id of the row for use as foreign key elsewhere...

```
INSERT INTO
    `table`
    (`url`)
VALUES
    ('http://example.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `id` = `id`
```

or

```
INSERT INTO
    `table`
    (`url`)
VALUES
    ('http://example.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `id` = `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
```

either works - not sure which is advisable - probably the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the use of REPLACE could help you to handle this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html ?